# Regex ignore Find and Replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to use Regex commands to find a string with a few random numbers, change some of them and leave others unchanged.

```
BEFORE: textureFile(A)[(B)] = INFO;

AFTER:  textureFile(A)[(B)] = NEWINFO
```

In this example, I want to change INFO, while leaving A and B unchanged.

I have this to find:

```
textureFile..\[.\] = .*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(textureFile\S+\s+=\s+)([^;]+);`

Replace with: `\1NEWINFO;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your simple example, it should suffice to search on the `=`:

**Find**

```
(= ).*
```

**Replace**

```
\1NEWINFO;
```

Notice I included the semi-colon in the replacement, but it is not in the find. The `.*` will eat the semi-colon when searching, so you need to add it back in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

A more specific solution would be:

Find what:

```
(textureFile\(.*\)\[\(.*\)\] = )(.*)
```

Replace with:

```
$1NEWINFO
```

with the option `. matches newline` disabled.